# django csrf token error - Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: python, django, cookies

I have enabled csrf token in django form and getting below error if i try to upload the file. Please help me to fix it.

**Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /upload**

my html form render like below.

```
<form id="uploadfile" action="/upload" class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="I4DEvg2nDPGkaGjrynMVGh5KfGdk3Z3z">
        <div class="dz-message needsclick" style="display: block;">
            Drop files here or click to upload.<br>
        </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="mycmd"></form>
```

My upload view code looks like below.

```
def upload(request): 
    # handle form upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cmd = request.POST.get('cmd','')
        form = Utils.Form()
        upfile = form.uploadFile(request)
        ....some code.....
        return HttpResponse("my response")
```

in settings.py i have enabled cookie and csrf like below.

```
........
........
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SENDFILE_BACKEND = 'sendfile.backends.development'
........
........
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
.......
```

Comment: I asume that, that HTML is the rendered one, and no your template.

Comment: I mean, do you have this `{% csrf_token %}` in template?

Comment: Are you submitting the form using ajax?

Comment: @Alasdair - yes ..using ajax. I am using dropzone.js

Comment: Have you tested submitting the form without ajax, to see whether that's the problem?

Comment: Also, you have `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True`, so make sure you are submitting the form from an https url.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try to send request with 'X-CSRFToken' header and put csrf token into it.
Perhaps it will help
[Django documentation - Cross Site Request Forgery protection - Ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)